# How to find the column that contains specific text? (VBA)

Tags: vba

I have the text "Investment Income" in cell O12 or R12 and I'm wondering what the vba code is to figure out if the text is in column O or column R?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic method. It will not check to see if the value is in both cells:

```
If InStr(Range("O12").Value, "Investment Income") Then
    MsgBox "It's in O12"
ElseIf InStr(Range("R12").Value, "Investment Income") Then
    MsgBox "It's in R12"
Else
    MsgBox "It's not in either of them."
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I should have specified that I want it to set a variable (say LastColumn) as either "O" or "R"...I can pretty much do the same thing but instead of the MsgBox, just set the variable, which should work!  Thanks again!